# Too many immutable objects creation within very short time in a long running thread in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, garbage-collection

I have an immutable data type as follows:

```
public class TestData  {
 private final double x;
 private final double y;

 public TestData (double xx, double yy) {
      x = xx;
      y = yy;
 }
```

}

Since `TestData` is immutable, I have to create a new object when `TestData` is used. In a long running thread I am creating too many objects within very short time. Now I am wondering is it an extra burden for GC to clear those objects or GC is smart enough removing short-lived objects? Is it a reason for increasing memory usages as long as my application is running?

```
public void test() {
TestData[] tempData = new TestData [5000];

while (true) {
   for (int i = 0; i < tempData.length; i++) {
        tempData[i] = new TestData(0.0, 0.0);
   }

   //process tempData
   tempData[5] = new  TestData(1.5, 8.5);
   //...
   tempData[55] = new  TestData(2.5, 3.5);
   //...
   tempData[100] = new TestData(0.0, 0.0); 
   //...
}
```

}

Should I change `TestData` mutable, and add a `reset()/set()` method so that I can reuse the same object again?

```
public void reset() {
    x = 0.0;
    y = 0.0;
}

public set(double xx, double yy) {
      x = xx;
      y = yy;
 }

   //process tempData
   tempData[5].set(1.5, 8.5);
   //...
   tempData[55].set(2.5, 3.5);
   //...
   tempData.reset(); 
   //...
```

Comment: Since you have an array, you are storing the instance, if you "reset" the value, you will use always the same instance so the previous `tempData` will be changed too. So you need to generate a new instance for every cells if you want them to have different values

Comment: Are you actually having memory problems? Unless you are, this kind of strategy is premature optimisation. The garbage collector is very clever, and sometimes trying to make things easier for it only causes problems.

Comment: Whether you should or shouldn't make your object mutable to improve performance can only be decided by reliably measuring your performance first. What you can definitely do though is make sure you minimise the scope of variables holding your objects.

Comment: Is it really necessary to have 5000 different immutable instances of the same value? Can't you just init the array with one single instance of TestData(0,0) ?

Comment: Profile. Slap a big chunk of objects (half a million to say a number) and run it under a profiler. If you can't live with what you see then change it

Comment: In fact `Integer` and other primitive wrappers that are built into Java are very similar to your objects. That means the garbage collector is built with many small and short-lived objects in mind and thus is quite good at handling those (which might include increasing memory instead of collecting them if memory is still available). To reduce the burden your application puts on the gc you could provide some sort of cache for common values (like 0/0) - much like Java does for `Integer` instances between -128 and 127.

Comment: What makes you think that the GC is the problem? What have you done to identify any issues? Not saying you are right or wrong, but it's hard to help without more information.

Comment: You could have a problem if your array was huge. Now since you reset the content at each loop iteration, your objects are eligible for collection.